# How to show advertises in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone

I write an App that shows all it's information in a UITableView.
Now I use the UIViewController to show 2 UITableViews inside of it.

The first UITableView shows the primary information ( this works fine ).

But now I want to show an advertisement in my App.
I decided to use a second UITableViewController with just one UITableViewCell, which isn't scrollable. ( this second UITableViewController is shown and useable )

The very big question for me is how can I show advertisements there?
I like to show something like a video which I could make with Adobe CS4. 
The phone doesn't like Flash, so which format could I use and how can I play it in an UITableViewCell?
Or, when it's better to show it in an UIView or something else, let me know.

Greetz
Wissensdurst

Answer (score 0):

There's an inbuilt [ad banner](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1747-how-to-implement-iad-on-your-iphone-applications/) class, and they're also launching a [video ad service](http://gigaom.com/video/apple-developing-in-stream-video-ads-for-ios-devices-2/) early next year. Or you could override UITableViewCell to include a video player in it which could play your ad.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a second TableView Controller? Just us the same and check for the indexPath.row or indexPath.section in you UITableView Delegate Methods. For instance:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    //show  specific informations
    }else if(indexPath.row > 0){
        //show comercial
    }else{
        //show all other rows
    }
}
```

or another thing you can use are the tableHeaderView or the tableFooterView. Those views are imageViews so you just can do e.g. 
`self.tableView.tableFooterView = (UIImageView*)myImageViewWithCommercialBanner;`

For you videos, flash is definitely a no go on iphone. Use the required formats in the Apple Documentations and you are fine. For example *.m4v is a commonly used format for this.

Comment: "Why do you want to use a second TableView Controller?" presumably because, as said in the question, that way the advert doesn't scroll off the screen.

Comment: Yes, that's also a good idea, but how Graham wrote, I need to show it permanent.

Comment: So I thought about using the didSelectedRowAtIndexPath-Method to open a link to our website. The height of these advertisementcell is just a few px and the addesigner asked me about using a video to use it as an eyecatcher. Now I tried to use MPMoviePlayerController but it doesn's seems to be the right thing to play a small video just in an UIImage/View.